Is armor that can be worn under clothing any less bothersome to rest in?
Using the optional rules from Xanathar's Guide to Everything, wearing medium or heavy armor can disrupt resting, as noted in this answer to a related question.
However, what about the various kinds of magical armor, such as mithral armor and molten bronze skin, which state that they can be worn "under normal clothes"? The implication seems to be that such armor is light, flexible, and comfortable enough not to impede movement. Is that a sufficient reason to allow unimpeded resting while wearing such armor?
In the case of molten bronze skin, its narrative conceit is that of a literal second skin, and its entry explicitly notes that "it doesn’t impede bodily functions." That would appear to apply directly to sleeping, inasmuch as sleep is a bodily function. Is there any reason to think otherwise, i.e., to apply the XGtE rule even to resting in molten bronze skin?
Does the fact that molten bronze skin explicitly calls out that bodily functions are unimpeded, but mithral armor does not, mean sleep is impeded in mithral armor?

Mithral armor impedes rest, RAW, but...
The short answer here is that there's an optional rule saying that medium and heavy armors impede rest, mithral armor doesn't say it doesn't impede rest, so it does as long as you use the optional rule. But...
Optional rules are prone to lacking exceptions.
5e generally adheres by specific rules beating general rules, but as an optional rule in XGtE, there are two issues for having a specific clause exempting the lighter mithral armors from the sleep penalty:

Anything printed before XGtE (including mithral armor) can't have accounted for a future optional rule.
Anything printed after XGtE (including molten bronze skin) is unlikely to explicitly call out all potentially-applicable optional rules.

As optional rules are less likely to get specific carve-outs in other content, it comes down to a DM call: is the intent that even sleeping in a mithral chain shirt impedes sleep due to them not specifying that sleeping in comfortable armor doesn't incur the penalty, or was it simply an oversight?
RAW is clear, but this warrants DM adjudication.
I'd hesitate to take molten bronze skin's "the armor can be worn under normal clothes, but it doesn't impede bodily functions" clause as an "exception proves the rule" case as molten bronze skin is so atypical that it warrants that clause even without the optional rule: yes, you're covered in bronze, but your body still works the same.
Ultimately I'd say the RAW is clear, so deciding whether to strictly adhere to it comes down to fun and balance. Mithral chain shirts and breastplates have minimal mechanical benefits, as neither one imposes disadvantage on dexterity (stealth) checks or has a strength requirement, so the only mechanical benefit they grant is the increased sturdiness of magic armor. Giving them the ability to let you sleep in them without penalty varies in utility based on the frequency of night ambushes, but to me it's a relatively small benefit for a lackluster pair of magic items that wouldn't imbalance anything. I'd be hard pressed to say that it would imbalance things to make all medium mithral armors exempt from the sleep penalty.
P.S.: Chain shirts are "worn between layers of clothing or leather," so they already can be worn under clothes (albeit not under all of the clothes) but this doesn't really affect the crux of your question.
P.P.S.: If you were interested in some older-gen precedent, in 3.5e, mithral armor outright counted as one category lighter. Under the equivalent rule in 3.5e (which was that sleeping in medium or heavy armor made you fatigued the next day) all medium mithral armor avoided that penalty, irrespective of whether it fit under clothes.

Interesting, although I'm not sure I agree with your "but versus and" logic. What, then, of demon skin, which is functionally identical to molten bronze skin apart from granting a different (but equally common) damage resistance -- yet says "and it doesn’t impede bodily functions" instead of "but"? Do we really have two items that are virtually identical, with similar narrative conceits (i.e., a fluid that becomes an armor-like second skin), one of which permits sleep and the other not, based on a different conjunction? Hm.

@screamline Good catch! I'll remove that part of the answer, but it's definitely weird that they're written so closely yet aren't the same.

RAW there is no penalty for resting in armor
The entire section on the requisites for a long rest is in the PHB:

A long rest is a period of extended downtime, at least 8 hours long, during which a character sleeps for at least 6 hours and performs no more than 2 hours of light activity, such as reading, talking, eating, or standing watch. If the rest is interrupted by a period of strenuous activity - at least 1 hour of walking, fighting, casting spells, or similar adventuring activity - the characters must begin the rest again to gain any benefit from it.

At least six hours sleep, no more than two hours of light activity, no more than one hour of strenuous activity: this is what is required for a long rest.  No mention is made of whether or not you are in armor.  RAW armor doesn't matter.
XGtE armor does not impede rest, just recovery

...sleeping in medium or heavy armor makes it difficult to recover fully during a long rest.

If you use the optional rules for sleeping in armor in XGtE, sleeping in armor doesn't impede rest per se - a long rest is not interrupted, it takes just as long to complete, and it is automatically successful.  What is impeded by sleeping in armor are the general benefits that come from resting.  Fewer HD are recovered and no levels of exhaustion are removed.  Interestingly, because the rest itself is not affected, all your class abilities that recharge on a long rest are unimpeded.
The rules themselves are clear: the armor has no effect if you just use the PHB; if you use XGtE there are effects for medium and heavy armor.  Mithral armor is from the Basic Rules (2014); it could not address the optional rules in XGtE (2017).  XGtE could have mentioned mithral armor, but didn't - however, Shivers' analysis is sound - we can't expect optional rules to comprehensively address exceptions.  Molten Bronze Skin is from Mythic Odysseys of Theros (2020) and could have addressed XGtE but didn't - but we can't expect exceptions to comprehensively address optional rules.
The DM chose this rule for a reason
If the optional rule from XGtE is in play, it is because the DM put it in play.  The DM needs to consider why they did so.  What were they trying to achieve by making rest less beneficial for characters in medium and heavy armor?  Was it increased verisimilitude?  Greater player attention to logistics?  Increasing the threat of night battles?  Encouraging players to return to town or base camp rather than resting in the field / dungeon?  A 'rest tax' on martial characters?
The DM needs to consider first their motivation for putting the rule in play, and then decide what will better serve that motivation.   It could be that these special armors are still subject to the penalties - reinforcing the idea that there are penalties for resting in armor.  Or it could be that these special armors are exceptions to the chosen rule, reinforcing the idea that the special armors are valuable rewards because they allow characters to offset the effects of the rule.
Once the DM knows which way they want to rule, anything else is a post hoc narrative justification, not an actual reason:
Why you can recover in mithral
"Mithral is a light, flexible metal".  The proximate source for the shirt is the mithril [sic] chain worn by Bilbo and Frodo.  Frodo wore the suit for five months (c. September to January) without any of his companions knowing he had it on.  Surely he slept in it, and it did not trouble his sleep.  A typical weighted blanket runs five to 20 pounds - and the half of the armor that is above the character when they sleep is not more than that.
Why you can't recover in mithral
Despite being described as "light", mithral armor is not RAW any lighter in weight than its armor type standard.  It is a medium or heavy armor and not explicitly exempt from the XGtE rule.
Why you can recover in bronze skin
It "contours to your skin" and "it doesn't impede bodily functions" (like sleep).
Why you can't recover in bronze skin
Sleep is an unimpeded bodily function, but recovering HD and removing exhaustion are not bodily functions, they are game effects not covered by the armor.  Having so much of your skin covered in bronze will impede your recovery by either carrying away your body heat if cold, or removing your ability to cool yourself by sweating if hot.

It's "mithral" by the way. :)

@Senmurv Is it, though?  Yes, apparently it is.  I wonder if that happened when ents became treants and balrogs became balors.

Me thinks you might be onto something there ;)
